# Why is the Typescript settings tab missing in my VS 2013 ASP.NET project properties?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm trying to migrate some javascript files to Typescript in a legacy ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I
I've created a Typescript file and the compilation from TS to JS works as expected, but I there is no "Typescript Build" Tab in my legacy project's properties.

I did not have this problem when working on a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project. How can I fix this in my legacy project? I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 1.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Wild guess: look at the project files with a text viewer, Notepad is fine.  Compare the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` values you see being used.

Comment: @Hans: Great guess! I was a ProjectGuid belonging to ASP.NET MVC. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 28):

I needed to add the following line to the csproj to import the typescript targets:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

Then I could see the typescript build options in the project settings.

Comment: You saved my day sir, Thanks!

Comment: worked for me although I had to change `MSBuildExtensionsPath32` to just `MSBuildExtensionsPath`

Answer (score 6):

As Hans Passant correctly hinted in the comments, the problem was the following ProjectGuid in my .csproj file: {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}

Once I removed that GUID from my project file and reloaded my project, the Typescript tab showed up in the project properties.

Comment: I must have initially skipped over the "reloaded my project" part, that works for me. I'm using VS2013.3, and once you add a TypeScript file to the solution, it notifies you of TS support being added. Reloading the project/solution then brings up the build tab.

Comment: Hmm.. this helped me to get TypeScript project tab, but now the project behave like a class library, because the removed GUID is for ASP.NET MVC5 (http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

Comment: This kind of works, but as Tomino pointed out, it removes web stuff in the process. I just re-added the guid and the web stuff is back.

Answer (score 3):

I have added "TypeScriptToolsVersion" in csproj.

```
  <Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
```

But it is Visual Studio 2013 RC2.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right solution since the test project I created does not have this config section either.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible cause of this is having an old Visual Studio version number in the `VisualStudioVersion` node in the .csproj file:

For VS 2013 it should be:

```
<VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

For VS 2015 it should be:

```
<VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

For VS 2017 it should be:

```
<VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your csproj has

> Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersi>on)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" >Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualS>tudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />

and still you have issue.

Do the below things:

1. Add a new typescript file in the project.
2. Build the solution.
3. Close and start the Visual Studio, Open the project.
4. Check the Typescript Tab in the project properties.

Comment: Your answer feels incomplete. Are you missing some details?

Comment: Thanks. I added the missing portion

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you get the correct settings in your Visual Studio project file:

1. Add a temp.ts file to your project via Visual Studio and save it (you may get a dialogue about Visual Studio looking up TypeScript types)
2. Your project file should have updated. Save it.
3. Close the solution and re-open it.
4. TypeScript Build Tab should be in the project properties.
5. Delete the temp.ts file.

(I derived this from Eric D. Johnson's comment here):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/98916/typescript-build-tab-not-showing-in-project-proper.html

Answer (score 1):

Missing TypeScript support may also be the problem. One way to solve this is to install the TypeScript NuGet package. This will also add the TypeScript Build menu in the project property pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 2013, but for VS2015, you just need to add a TypeScript file to the root folder of the project and it will popup a dialog asking you if you want to configure the project for TypeScript.  Simple!