# There is no TypeScript Build option in project settings Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, build, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've created a MVC project templated web application but there is no TypeScript Build option in project options-properties.

How can i find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130665/why-is-the-typescript-settings-tab-missing-in-my-vs-2013-asp-net-project-propert) post.

Should delete ProjectGuid from project file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you do not have the typescript definitions?
Anyway, you have to follow a series of steps to set up typescript in your solution. I need more information, but do you have TSD installed?

> Is a package manager to search and install Typescript definition files directly from the community driven DefinitelyTyped repository.

You have it installing it globally with "npm install tsd -g" and after that you create a tsd.json file inside your solution, typping in your console "tsd init" that creates the typpings folder.

Comment: No, there should be TypeScript Build option in project's properties.